# Prove that a NxN grid can be colored using n colors such that each color appear once each row and column

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Just like a simpler Sudoku game, given n, show that nxn grid can be colored using n colors so that each color appears once for each row/column.

I see that each row/column forms a complete graph so that we need at least n colors for each row/column. But I'm stuck at bringing those together and show that n is also the maximum color needed to color the grid.

Any hint? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to add 1 more constraint that I would need to prove also for the case that k (k less than n) row is already given. I think in that case the shifting answer would not be correct right?

Comment: Pick something for first row, and then simply shift colors by one e.g. to the left on each row.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You could consider the multiplication table for a group of order $n$ (the cyclic group always exists)

Comment: Order your N colors in a sequence $a_1, \dots a_N$ color the first row this way and cyclically start each row i with the color $a_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the squares of the grid coordinates $(x,y)$ where $0 \leq x, y \leq n-1$. Give the square $(x,y)$ colour $i$ where $0\leq i \leq n-1$, and $x+y \equiv i \pmod n$. This colouring satisfies the conditions required.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

$$\begin{matrix}
 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
2 & 3 & \cdots & n & 1\\
3 & 4 & \cdots & 1 & 2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
n & 1 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1\\
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Find solutions for $n = 2$ and $3$. Then try for $n=4$. (Starting with simple cases is always a good strategy.)

Hint in general. Fill in the first row any way you like. Then think about a shift to the right.